# HDMI port not working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, 22.04, hdmi, hp

I have ubuntu 22.04 on my HP Victus 16, When I try to attach another screen using HDMI port it don't pick up the signal, but when I use Dock with c-type port it works, can someone help me to resolve the HDMI port issue...

Comment: If you turn your machine off completely, then plug in the HDMI screen, then turn on that HDMI connected screen and only then do you boot up your machine... do you see any sign of life on that HDMI screen?

Comment: @darth_epoxy, I found out the problem, actually the HDMI port is coming out from graphic card and graphic card driver is not found, so it don't give any output